# How to make the button not to change the background on clicking

Tags: qt

I have the QPushButton that changes own icon by clicking.

```
// in the slot
btn->setIcon( expr ? icon1 : icon2 );
```

How I can disable the switching of the background color of the button, when user clicked and released the button?

I need just change the button icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use stylesheet with your desired background color, i.e.

```
QPushButton{ background: red;}
QPushButton:disabled{background: red;}
QPushButton:pressed{background: red;}
QPushButton:hover{background: red;}
```

Stylesheets for button you can set in the "Design" tab of your project or in the code i.e.

```
btn->setStyleSheet("your style sheet string");
```

Comment: thanks for the hint. I solved the problem this way:     btn->setStyleSheet( "background-color: rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0% )" ); I need to examine more carefully the work with styles.